# Проблема с удалением элементов массива js

Tags: javascript

Недавно начал изучать js. Я пытаюсь удалить элемент массива с помощью splice с моего to-do list, но столкнулся с проблемой что это работает только на первый элемент и удаляет из всего массива через один (кнопки на втором и тд элементах не работают).

Хотелось бы узнать что я делаю не так и можно ли как-то это исправить. Вот мой код.

````
delTask.addEventListener('click', function(){
    todoArr.forEach(function(item, index){
        todoArr.splice(index, 1);
        displayTasks();
        localStorage.setItem('ulli', JSON.stringify(todoArr));
    });
});```
.
````

Comment: а что ты ожидаешь получить удаляя элементы из массива, по которому уже проходишь циклом в текущий момент?

Comment: ну вот например цикл должен у тебя быть по 10 элементам, а внутри ты из него же удаляешь, то что должен делать forEach?

Comment: И вообще непонятно зачем тут цикл…

Comment: Массив у меня уже заполненный. Я хочу удалять элементы по индексу и поэтому прохожусь циклом чтобы определить индекс. Либо как это можно сделать по другому?

Comment: так вы посмотрите в документацию метода `splice`. как он работает. есть в документации циклы?